# How can I open port 443?

Tags: ssl

I'm trying to host a small node application on a digital ocean droplet running ubuntu 14.04. In local development the site works fine over https, however on the server the site doesn't get displayed and the server does not throw an error, the connection is just refused. I ran `nmap localhost` and port 443 was closed. How can I open it?

Comment: Is your web server configured for HTTPS?

Comment: Sometimes `sudo ufw allow out 443/tcp` is necessary to allow outgoing connections from installed apps.

Answer (score 28):

```
sudo ufw allow 443/tcp
```

And have a read through the docs on Ubuntu UFW interface on iptables. This should open it for your web application.

Also make sure that your application is serving off the external IP as well as the internal. The app.js file there is usually a setting to specify a interface for it to run on. 0.0.0.0 should run it on both internal and external.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

Comment: When I run `sudo ufw status verbose` it says inactive. Should I `sudo ufw enable`? Because it's inactive it isn't the thing that's closing the port then right?

Comment: `allow 443/tcp` also lets AWS command-line tools work.   Thanks!  https://requester.mturk.com/developer/tools/clt

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS I was missing this command:

`sudo a2enmod ssl`

Among other things, this will actually enable the ssl module.

Hat tip to this thorough source for configuring SSL on Apache on Ubuntu: https://www.maketecheasier.com/apache-server-ssl-support/

Answer (score 1):

Running `sudo a2ensite default-ssl` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.
1) Create and install 2 certificates to /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt and /etc/ssl/private/server.key:
https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html

2) Edit the file /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf to reference those certificates and execute a2ensite on that file:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04